# Ubuntu web browser not loading in 14.04

Tags: browser, qt5

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.2 32 bit platform.  When I launch ubuntu web browser GUI window opens but it's white empty. I launched it in terminal `/usr/bin/webbrowser-app` it's the same, it only prints:

```
  /usr/bin/webbrowser-app
  Loaded 1 UA override(s) from file:///usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/Extras/Browser/ua-overrides-desktop.js
```

I checked out the dependencies:

```
ldd /usr/bin/webbrowser-app
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77d1000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0xb72b5000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0xb6e5d000)
libQt5Quick.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5 (0xb6afe000)
libQt5Sql.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0xb6ac0000)
libQt5Qml.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0xb66e2000)
libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0xb659c000)
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0xb5f7a000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb5e91000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb5e74000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb5cc6000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb5caa000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb5c90000)
libicui18n.so.52 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52 (0xb5a82000)
libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52 (0xb5910000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb590b000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb57ff000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb57f6000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb57af000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77d3000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xb5787000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0xb5731000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0xb569f000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb564d000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xb5518000)
libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52 (0xb3eab000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb3e6d000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xb3dcd000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0xb3db0000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xb3d87000)
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0xb3d6e000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xb3d5b000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0xb3d57000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xb3d51000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0xb3d4d000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0xb3d35000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0xb3d2f000)
libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0xb3d2b000)
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0xb3d27000)
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0xb3d1f000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xb3cfd000)
libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0xb3cfa000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xb3cf4000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0xb3ce6000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xb3cde000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xb3cda000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb3cd3000)
```

I manually installed some libraries from source code in the past, their default path is `/usr/local/lib`
I don't think it caused the problem.
It's not a clean installation. I did upgrades every year.

Would you please guide me to locate the problem?

EDIT: I tested it again after installing upgrades. Nothing has changed. I don't know how to debug it.