# Ubuntu Browser - not complete?

Tags: 14.04, browser

[Ubuntu web browser not loading in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640423/ubuntu-web-browser-not-loading-in-14-04)

I checked the above post, but there has been no answer for over 2 months.

I just discovered this browser today.  I guess it was installed when I upgraded to 14.04 a few weeks ago.

Here are the photos of what I get when I run it.

Access the browser through Unity:
[image: In Unity Search bar]

The open window only:
[image: The open browser]

Full screen with no menu (its small but mouse is in top left corner)
[image: Full screen with no menu, etc.]
(I have dual monitors, the blue border on the right is the next monitor.  I reduced the size not to consume excess bandwidth on viewers.)

I would like to either repair or remove it.  I have searched for install instructions but found none.  I don't know if `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu_browser` is the correct instruction or not, so here I am asking.

Thank you

Comment: Apparently the browser package is called `webbrowser-app`. Reinstalling by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall webbrowser-app` shouldn't do any harm.

Comment: The name of the browser app in the Ubuntu Software Center is *Ubuntu web browser* in case you're ready to give up and uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  I tried reinstalling it and it still didn't work. I removed it and installed it again, but it still didn't work so I removed it.  Thank you all for your attempt to help.]

Comment: `Check the CAPTCHA box, and we'll be out of your way.`

There is no captcha box.  I get to the point of copying the script into the box and nothing!  no button to push, etc.  It just keeps me hung up or makes me do it all over again.

Comment: OK, the captcha doesn't like me to paste text into the answer box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reinstalling and it did not work.  I removed it and reinstalled it and it still did not work.  I finally removed it and just don't expect to use it.